# maven-shade-plugin:pom:3.2.4 failed to transfer from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during previous attempt error

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I was importing a project that has been developed by someone.

However, when I import the project, I kept getting this error in pom.xml:

> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:pom:3.2.4 failed to
> transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous
> attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and
> resolution is not reattempt untill the update interval of central has
> elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer
> artifact org.apache.maven.plugin...

How can I solve this issue?

This is the project's pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>eLoki2</groupId>
<artifactId>eLoki2</artifactId>
<version>0.6.0</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.argparse4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>argparse4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.36.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
            
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.joonasvali.naturalmouse</groupId>
      <artifactId>naturalmouse</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>eLoki2</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- fix for Selenium 4 https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10132#issuecomment-1035028801 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>core.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>l4j-clui</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>launch4j</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <headerType>console</headerType>
                    <jar>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.jar</jar>
                    <outfile>${project.build.directory}/eLoki2.exe</outfile>
                    <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                    <classPath>
                        <mainClass>core.Main</mainClass>
                        <preCp>anything</preCp>
                    </classPath>
                    <jre>
                        <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
                        <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                    </jre>
                    <versionInfo>
                        <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                        <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                        <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                        <copyright>2021 Chonglun Chen</copyright>
                        <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
                        <txtProductVersion>1.0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
                        <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                        <companyName>York University</companyName>
                        <internalName>eLoki2</internalName>
                        <originalFilename>eLoki2.exe</originalFilename>
                    </versionInfo>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have tried the smart import, and imported manually and kept getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version you're using is not the latest one (3.4.1), and the `<configuration>` tag should be outside of the `<executions>` tag.

Take a look at the official documentation on how to configure the *maven-shade-plugin* here:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html